# Prevent TextBox in ListViewItem Expanding

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a `TextBox` inside a `StackView` inside a `ListViewItem` and I want it to wrap rather than expand when the contents becomes wider than the available space.

The LVI is defined by this template:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type custom:FreeCommentQuestion}">
        <StackPanel Margin="5">
            <Label Content="{Binding Text}"/>
            <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Comment}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

And the `ListView` is inside a `ScrollViewer` in a `TabItem`:

```
    <TabItem Header="Testing" >
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </TabItem>
```

It all looks fine:

[image: Textbox1]

Until I type too much in:

[image: TextBox2]

I could set the MaximumWidth in code but this seems like it ought to be unecessary.

The ListView also doesnt seem to be shrinking back down when the window has been resized bigger and then smaller again.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Try `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` on the scrollviewer.

Comment: @the.Doc That doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the scrollviewer as the default `ListView` template contains one.
Therefore you can remove the outer scrollviewer and set `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` on the `ListView`

```
        <ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Alternatively, use an `ItemsControl` and keep the outer `ScrollViewer`

```
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

ItemsControl is a lot more basic than the `ListView` but it looks to be more suited to your scenario.